# curl command for starting a Java Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, curl, terminal

I have followed a Spring Boot tutorial [Spring Boot and OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) that has had the `curl` command to start the project:

[image]

But this curl command doesn't work. When I changed the command adding `-o file_name` parameter, it downloaded an empty file. I also create a listing of curl verbose mode. How to make curl work? Here are the commands in the terminal:

```sh
u@apu:~/tymcz$ curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d style=web -d name=simple | tar -xzvf -
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    21    0     0  100    21      0     54 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    54

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
u@apu:~/tymcz$ curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d style=web -d name=simple
u@apu:~/tymcz$ curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d style=web -d name=simple -o starter.tgz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    21    0     0  100    21      0     48 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    48
u@apu:~/tymcz$ stat starter.tgz 
  File: starter.tgz
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 24249767    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/       u)   Gid: ( 1000/       u)
Access: 2020-12-21 16:24:54.532084967 +0100
Modify: 2020-12-21 16:24:54.532084967 +0100
Change: 2020-12-21 16:24:54.532084967 +0100
 Birth: -
u@apu:~/tymcz$ cat starter.tgz 
u@apu:~/tymcz$
```

```sh
u@apu:~/tymcz$ curl -vv https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d style=web -d name=simple 2> curlvvoutput
u@apu:~/tymcz$ cat curlvvoutput 
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
*   Trying 104.20.5.247...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149999 ms for 3 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55fa61d09ec0)
* Connected to start.spring.io (104.20.5.247) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Palo Alto; O=Pivotal Software, Inc.; OU=Spring; CN=*.spring.io
*  start date: Mar 10 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 28 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "start.spring.io" matched cert's "*.spring.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55fa61d09ec0)
> POST /starter.tgz HTTP/2
> Host: start.spring.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 21
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 256)!
< HTTP/2 404 
< date: Mon, 21 Dec 2020 15:23:02 GMT
< content-length: 0
< set-cookie: __cfduid=de04ceac3aa5f687fc279625eb9e028901608564181; expires=Wed, 20-Jan-21 15:23:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.spring.io; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
< vary: Origin
< vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< via: 1.1 google
< cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
< cf-request-id: 07277ea3c20000416f47042000000001
< expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
< server: cloudflare
< cf-ray: 60529a193e35416f-HAM
< 
* Connection #0 to host start.spring.io left intact
u@apu:~/tymcz$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`style` is not a valid parameter name anymore. Use `-d dependencies=web` instead:

```
curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d dependencies=web -d name=simple | tar -xzvf -
```

For a full list of available parameters use:

```
curl https://start.spring.io
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/0.4.x/reference/html/command-line.html